# Acquire a single-variable function by slicing a 3d graph along a given line

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions

Consider my Calculus 2 math problem: Given a function `f[x,y]=x^2-3xy` and two vectors `a = {1,2} and b = {1,1}`. Spanning a linear combination `a + k*b` gives a line that defines a plane perpendicular to the x/y plane, that cuts a cross section of function `f[x,y]`, which gives a new function of just one variable. Find the formula for this function and its derivative with respect to the line.

I can plot the function using `Plot3D`, and I can acquire a cross section parallel to the x or y axis by holding x or y constant. But I don't know how to do this when I want a diagonal cross section.

I want to plot the function, plot the required cross section and acquire a formula for the 2d function.

Comment: Don't you mean a plane? A line will intersect a surface in a point, and not a curve.

Comment: Yes, my explanation is not rigorous enough. The 3D graph's cross section is cut by a plane that is perpendicular to the x/y plane, and is going through the given line.

Comment: I see, so aren't you just looking for $y=f(x,mx+k)$, where you can derive $m$ and $k$ from the two-point equation of a line?

Comment: My knowledge of analytical geometry is not good enough to instantly know what you mean, but you could say that I am looking for a function that takes as an input some linear combination of `1 * a + k * b` and gives me the appropriate value from the range of my original function `f[x,y]`

Comment: Try this: `Plot[f[x, InterpolatingPolynomial[{a, b}, x]], {x, -5, 5}]`.

Comment: Well, that certainly produced an anwser. Now I have to do my research and find out why and how. Is there a way for Mathematica to give me the formula for this parabola that I got now? Also would this work for any multivariable function, and not just polynomials?

Either way, thank you for the help you've given me!

Comment: Just evaluate `f[x, InterpolatingPolynomial[{a, b}, x]]` with `x` not assigned to anything.